# Lucky game of a success and failure probability. (Advanced probability exams problem)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, distribution-theory

**Problem :**

> One random experiment has two possible results : Success (S) with probability $p$ and Failure (F) with probability $q=1-p$. We consider the following lucky game : We conduct independent repetitions of the experiment until we come across the first Success. If the success comes at the first repetition, we win $2\$$, if it comes at the second repetition, we win $1\$$, if it comes at the third one then we win $1/2 \$$ and so on.
>
> $(a)$ Find the expected profit for a player in this game.
>
> $(b)$ If $p=1/3$, is it fair that taking part in such a game costs $1\$$ ?

**Discussion :**

The problem above was an exams question in one of the first "advanced" probability courses on the Mathematics Department of the School of Applied Mathematics and Physics of NTUA.

My thoughts on it, is first to describe the function of the winning amount in terms of the winning repetition step :

$$w_n = \frac{2}{2^n} = 2^{1-n}$$
and we observe that the winning amount gets cut in the half as described in the problem form.

Now, judging from the form of the game, I guess the distribution that it follows is a **geometric** one, which means that :

$$P\{X=k\} = (1-p)^{k-1}p$$

How would I find the expected profit for a player though ? I wasn't able to solve the problem in the exams, I would really appreciate if someone could provide a hint or elaborate thoroughly so I can grasp what I couldn't understand.

Comment: Hopefully you found my answer below helpful; if so would you please consider upvoting / accepting. Stackexchange sites survive by people donating their time to help each other, and that is an easy way to give back. Thanks!

Comment: @owen88 I was the one that upvoted and as you can see by my reputation I know how it works. I just want to wait for the possibility of a more detailed answer, accepting isn't obligatory. For instance, I would like to see the final result or how one would take one part b.

Comment: I completely agree that upvoting isn't obligatory; I'm happy to give more detail below if you'd like that, but I also think that its good to leave the option for people to finish the question themselves. Given that you would like more help, I'll update my answer.

Comment: updated, to include further detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that this follows a geometric distribution; if $W$ is the winnings of the game, then the expectation can be written by conditioning on the round in which the game is won; let $N \sim \text{Geom}(p)$ be the round in which the game is won, then

$$\mathbf E[W] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbf E[W \, | \, N = n] \mathbf P[N=n].$$

You have already provided the formula for $\mathbf P[N = n] = (1-p)^{n-1}p$, as well as the formula for the value won if the game ends in round $n$

$$\mathbf E [ W \, | \, N = n] = 2^{2-n},$$

(note that my formula differs from yours by a factor of $2$, since I assume that the first round is $n = 1$, which matches the standard definition of a geometric variable. Hence the expectation is

$$ \mathbf E[W] = 2p \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1-p}{2} \right)^{n-1} 
 = 2p \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{1-p}{2}\right)^n.$$

This can now be solved using the identity for the geometric series: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac1{1-x}$, when $ 0 \leq x < 1$, so we have

$$ \mathbf{E}[W] = 2p \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1 - p}{2}} = 2p \frac{2}{1+p} = \frac{4p}{1+p}.$$

When $p = 1/3$ we see that $\mathbf{E}[W] = 1$, so if the game costs 1 dollar to enter, then we would expect neither to make a gain or loss.

Comment: Really well explained solution by the way. I just wanted to see the final results in order to clarify the though for the last part.

Comment: No problem at all!